# When should we use reference to import an ambient module in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript docs are vague about when triple-slash referencing should be used.

The only part of the docs that explicitly suggest using it, is the [ambient modules section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#ambient-modules).

As far as I can tell, we can (and should) always use `import` instead of triple-slash directives to import missing types, even when it is from ambient module (d.ts files with module type declarations for modules that do not have a TypeScript file).

Am I missing something?

From [Pitfalls of Namespaces and Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#pitfalls-of-namespaces-and-modules):

> A common mistake is to try to use the /// <reference ... /> syntax to
> refer to a module file, rather than using an import statement. ... The
> compiler will try to find a .ts, .tsx, and then a .d.ts with the
> appropriate path. If a specific file could not be found, then the
> compiler will look for an ambient module declaration. Recall that
> these need to be declared in a .d.ts file.

The [Triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) docs section does not really add any additional insight on use cases.

Also, the following official [TypeScript ESLint rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/triple-slash-reference/) seems to confirm that `import` should generally always be used instead of the triple-slash directive:

> TypeScript's /// triple-slash references are a way to indicate that
> types from another module are available in a file. Use of triple-slash
> reference type directives is generally discouraged in favor of
> ECMAScript Module imports.